# How to convert a hash to a single object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having an array of object in the below format:

```
var log=[
{
  billkey:"Name",
  billvalue:"ABC"
},
{ 
  billkey:"Department",
  billvalue:"Computer"
}];
```

which I want to convert in a single object like:

```
var log={
       "Name":"ABC",
       "Department":"Computer"
     };
```

I've tried the following approach:

```
for(var i=0;i<log.length;++i){
   pushToAry(log[i].billkey, log[i].billvalue);
}

function pushToAry(name, val) {
 var obj = {};
 obj[name] = val;
 ary.push(obj);
 }
```

But it will push a new object every time into the ary array, which results into:

```
var ary =[
    0:{
      "Name":"ABC"
    },
    1:{ 
      "Department":"Computer"
    }];
```

How could I convert this array of object into an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to use a loop, you can do it like this :

```js
var log = [
  {
    billkey: "Name",
    billvalue: "ABC"
  },
  {
    billkey: "Department",
    billvalue: "Computer"
  }];
  var result = {};
  log.forEach(x => result[x.billkey] = x.billvalue);
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

In ES6 this is quite clean:

```
let result = {};

for (let {billkey, billvalue} of log)
    result[billkey] = billvalue;
```

or if you prefer "functional" style:

```
let result = Object.assign(...log.map(x => (  {[x.billkey]: x.billvalue} )))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to return object.

```js
var log = [{
  billkey: "Name",
  billvalue: "ABC"
}, {
  billkey: "Department",
  billvalue: "Computer"
}];

var result = log.reduce((r, e) => (r[e.billkey] = e.billvalue, r), {});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < log.length; i++)
    obj[log[i].billkey] = log[i].billvalue;
```

First, I prepare an empty object to store reult to. Then I go through the log and in every iteration, I extract the log record's key (`log[i].billkey`) and value (`log[i].billvalue`) and use it to add the new member to the result: `obj[...key...] = ...value...;`.

Comment: Please add explanation.

Comment: Try evaluating every step in Your head - it goes like: `obj['Name'] = 'ABC';` `obj['Department'] = 'Computer';`

Comment: Mate, I know how your code works but point of answer is to help everyone and explanation is a very vital part of it. Just putting code is not good enough. You should also explain **What and Why** have you changed? And next time someone requests you politely, please address it with a polite response instead of *evaluating every step in Your head*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14840784)

Comment: @Rajesh: I am sorry if You consider my reply impolite, I didn't mean it. I'll add some explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Joseph: How does my answer not answer the original question? ("How could I convert this array of object into an object?")

Comment: At the moment that I marked this answer was a code-only answer, I can rollback this now.

Comment: @RomanHocke note SO is a portal for everyone. Beginners as well as Experts. Yes we can read your code and understand what it does but that will never signify **Why**. Why did you choose `for` over `forEach`, `for..of` or any other looping structure. Why do we need `obj` etc. Also its not good for an answer if it asks reader to read through entire code just to deduce simple points. This is where explanation comes. In many answers, you will even see code is collapsed as explanation clarifies everything and reader can take effort to expand to read code. We are here ho help, not code for others :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to *reduce* it to the required object - see demo below:

```js
var log=[{billkey:"Name",billvalue:"ABC"},{ billkey:"Department",billvalue:"Computer"}];

var result = log.reduce(function(p,c){
  p[c.billkey] = c.billvalue;
  return p;
},{})

console.log(result);
```